# Formatear HTML para mostrar en la vista

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

Estoy usando Laravel 5.4, y recupero un texto desde la base de datos formateado utilizando ckeditor

```
<p><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu</strong></p>
```

Se que en blade se utiliza {!! !!} para darle el formato pero esta vez utilizo ajax, y quiero setear este texto en un accesor de Laravel

```
public function getNoticiaAttribute($value)
{
    return $value;
}
```

Aca tendría que devolver el valor seteado como si fuera blade con {!! !!}

La información traida es por axios:

```
searchData() {
   axios.post('/news/search', $('#frmSearchNews').serialize()).then(res => {
      this.noticias = res.data;
   });
}
```

Comment: en ajax basta con que imprimas la data que te retorna en el success, solamente pones data en la funcion success y pones 
 `console.log(data);` y veras como llega pra imprimirlo.

Comment: Pero quiero mostrarlo en pantalla, dentro de un  <h2>, renderizando las etiqeutas html que traigo de la base de datos @SebastiánLagosYañez

Comment: Cuando por ajax llamas a una action que te devuelve eso que sucede??

Answer (score 0):

por defecto cuando usas ckeditor este genera codigo html el cual lo guardas en tu base de datos y lo repuras 
podrias identificar el area donde deseas agregar el texto por un id ejemplo

```
<h2 id="myIdH2">textoz</h2>
```

para poner cualquier valor en el seria por javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myIdH2").innerHTML = "lo que sea";
```

espero te sea util !!